# web-scraped string into if then statement in Python

Tags: python, string, decimal

I'm new to coding, please bear with me. how can I convert a web-scraped string result (a decimal point) into an actual numerical value to create if-then statements from?

ie: 60.1=exchange_rate as a string, but I need it as a number. I've tried this:

```
if (float(exchange_rate)) < 1:
       print("hi")
```

I'm getting an error that says:

```
if float(exchange_rate)) > 1:
                           ^
SyntaxError: unmatched ')'
```

Comment: Double check if your parentheses match into pairs and if you have saved the file, ;).

Comment: Your code is different from what you think. The error message shows that there are one left parenthesis and two right parentheses (an error), which is different from what your example shows.